# Link to function instead of website

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have made a contentscript which "injects" the following into a website:

```
< a href="somewebsite.html">mytext< /a>
```

The trouble I'm facing is that I want to link it to a function in my chrome extension instead. Something like:

```
< a href="mychromeextensionfunction">mytext< /a>.
```

How would I manage to do that, Is it even possible to link to a chrome extension function?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that through the `href` attribute; you need the `onClick` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

That explains it, Thanks for putting me in the right direction : )

Here's a sample code of how you could do it.

> link_dom.onclick=function (evt) {
>               alert('hello');
>   }